# Arc length and parameterization

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find the arc length of the closed part of the curve $9ay^{2}\ =\ x\left(x-3a\right)^{2}$.

We could just try to call $F = 9ay^{2}\ -\ x\left(x-3a\right)^{2}$, find the derivative of y wrt x and then integrate from 0 to 3a, and so multiply by 2, because there is the part with y>0 and the part with y<0. But this is going to be troublesome.

So, i reduced the function $y = \frac{x^{3/2}-3a\sqrt{x}}{3 \sqrt{a}}$. I thought that $S=\int _{0}^{3a}\sqrt{1+y'²}dx$ would be half of the total arc length. But, after getting the answer and comparing it with the book's answer, apparently this give the total arc length. Why?

Comment: I know this isn't the same question but does this help you? https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/the-perimeter-of-the-loop-of-the-curve-3ay2xleftxaright2-is/

Comment: Perhaps they were only considering the curve as a function when calculating the arc length.

Comment: You may have made some mistake in calculations. What is the answer you get?

Comment: If you edit to state what you got for $y'$ and what is the final integral set up you had, it will help in finding where you made a mistake.